# Flutter build web in existing project keeps failing

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I tried to build the web in existing flutter apps by doing following steps

```
1. flutter channel beta
2. flutter config --enable-web
3. flutter create .
4. flutter run -d chrome
```

From https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web

But i dont know where i made a mistake or is this the issues with futter web build, It keeps failing. Running those command shows this screen.

[image]

**Here is the stacktrace**

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following UnsupportedError was thrown building Builder:
Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem

The relevant error-causing widget was:
MaterialApp org-dartlang-app:///packages/qpal/main.dart:13:12

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
package:dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 196:49  throw_
package:dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/io_patch.dart 241:5               _operatingSystem
package:dart-sdk/lib/io/platform_impl.dart 62:40                                      get operatingSystem
package:dart-sdk/lib/io/platform.dart 73:45                                           get _operatingSystem
package:dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/utils.dart 77:6     get
package:dart-sdk/lib/io/platform.dart 97:40                                           get operatingSystem
package:platform/src/interface/local_platform.dart 21:45                              get operatingSystem
package:platform/src/interface/platform.dart 41:38                                    get isIOS
package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart 83:20                              requestNotificationPermissions
package:qpal/services/firebase_helper.dart 41:23                                      requestNotification
package:qpal/main.dart 57:20                                                          initState
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4355:58                                    [_firstBuild]
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4201:5                                     mount
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3194:13                                    inflateWidget
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 2988:12                                    updateChild
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5445:14                                    mount
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3194:13                                    inflateWidget
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 2988:12                                    updateChild
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4243:16                                    performRebuild
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3947:5                                     rebuild
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4206:5                                     [_firstBuild]
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4201:5                                     mount
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3194:13                                    inflateWidget
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4201:5                                     mount
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3194:13                                    inflateWidget
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5551:32                                    mount
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3194:13                                    inflateWidget
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 2988:12                                    updateChild
package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart 591:16                                       mount
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3194:13                                    inflateWidget
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 2988:12                                    updateChild
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4243:16                                    performRebuild
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3947:5                                     rebuild
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4206:5                                     [_firstBuild]
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4381:11                                    [_firstBuild]
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4201:5                                     mount
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3194:13                                    inflateWidget
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 2988:12                                    updateChild
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4243:16                                    performRebuild
from splash
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3947:5                                     rebuild
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4206:5                                     [_firstBuild]
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4201:5                                     mount
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3194:13                                    inflateWidget
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 2988:12                                    updateChild
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5445:14                                    mount
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3194:13                                    inflateWidget
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 2988:12                                    updateChild
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4243:16                                    performRebuild
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3947:5                                     rebuild
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4206:5                                     [_firstBuild]
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4381:11                                    [_firstBuild]
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4201:5                                     mount
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3194:13                                    inflateWidget
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 2988:12                                    updateChild
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5445:14                                    mount
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3194:13                                    inflateWidget
package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 999:5                                        mount
package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 942:16                                       <fn>
package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 2412:19                                    buildScope
package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 941:12                                       attachToRenderTree
package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 818:24                                       attachRootWidget
package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 804:7                                        <fn>
package:dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/isolate_helper.dart 50:19       internalCallback

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: Can you share your main.dart and firebase_helper.dart classes too?

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a new project and copy extra dependencies and devDependencies to new pubspec.yml, copy whole lib folder and check whether it is running. If it runs, then check your sdk version in new project and old project and try to make them same.

I faced similar issue and tried above which solved my problem.

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `Platform.IOS` or `Platform.Android`. If you use this you will see an exception.
I had the same problem and I solved it like that.

Comment: Remove from where?

Answer (score 0):

@ Thiago Silva (https://stackoverflow.com/users/8945078/thiago-silva) ,Indeed, the error is sometimes triggered due to the fact that your code still references platform specific calls. For instance, the error

```
"Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem"
```

is triggered in this line of loginBloc code:

```
if(Platform.isIOS && Config.enableAppleAuthForIOS)
  firebaseAuthWidgets("apple_login_icon",authService,_signInWithApple),
```

This is basically because , in this case, the OS really doesnt expose webapp from accessing system and authenticating the app as a result.

Just remove such vestiges of code remaining from an edited android/ios or macos app.